# How to control zoom after search has been executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I search for an address on this map it zooms in too much where the map is not useful. I have tried adjusting the map bounds, but it did not help. I think I am on the right path, but Its just not working. Can someone help me fix this?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
 #googft-mapCanvas {
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.controls {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 300px;
}
#pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.pac-container {
    font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter your address here">
<div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>
<script>
function initialize() {
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
    if (isMobile) {
        var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
        viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
    }

    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
    mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '1000px';
    mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '300px';
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.64936217820852, -90.53628850000001),
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    });
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        map: map,
        heatmap: {
            enabled: false
        },
        query: {
            select: "col26",
            from: "11Q0B7iRayT2JIOBl8_VRUmitimhX1W01byuFDnAv",
            where: ""
        },
        options: {
            styleId: 2,
            templateId: 2
        }
    });
    if (isMobile) {
        var legend = document.getElementById('googft-legend');
        var legendOpenButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-open');
        var legendCloseButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-close');
        legend.style.display = 'none';
        legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
        legendCloseButton.style.display = 'block';
        legendOpenButton.onclick = function () {
            legend.style.display = 'block';
            legendOpenButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
        legendCloseButton.onclick = function () {
            legend.style.display = 'none';
            legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.64936217820852, -90.53628850000001),
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        title: "Your New Home",
    });
     // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } 
      else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
      // now let's move the marker
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by ""it zooms in too much where the map is not useful"?  Can you provide an example of an address that does that?  What are you expecting to happen? What is the maximum zoom that you want to see?

Comment: If you search for 700 Clark Ave, St. Louis, MO 63102 it will zoom in so that all you see is the building that you are searching for. Im not sure on the maximum zoom, I would like to play around with that. I would like to maybe see the boarding school districts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in you code, you use `map.fitBounds(bounds);`, which `bounds` is the `place.geometry.viewport` returned from the search result, which by default zoom in as much as it can. Instead, you want to pan to the new location, which save your current zoom level. Look at [this jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1oqzajgx/) for more information.

Comment: How would I change this to zoom to 17 instead of the current bounds. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might able to use the setZoom in the map class. also look at the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map